# MySQL field to save ship to country list

Tags: mysql, sql

I am looking for the best practice to save a list of two letters country id in a mysql table field. I have a products table and I want each product to have a column with a list or countries that can be shipped to.

The ideas I have in my mind is to make another table for shipcountries like that:

```
item_id         int,
ship_country    char(2)
```

but for every item will be may entries in this table, so if the item ships to 200 countires will be 200 rows in this table. The idea is I need this field to be searchable to be able to search for items that ship to specific countires so I can not use a text field to store all countries list.

The second idea I have is to use one bit for every country in a bigint field but I think will be hard in searching.

How to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me like a `many-to-many relationship` between your product table and your country table.

So you should have a product table, a country table and a new table in between to make the link.

country table can be like that

```
country_id         int,
country_code       char(2),
country_name       varchar(100)
```

the table in between, let's call id `product_country` can be defined like this:

```
product_id         int,
country_id         int
```

Comment: This is what I already said above, the bad thing about this will be may be over 200 rows for each item in the county/product table.

Comment: @daliaessam It seems to me like the best solution though ;) I won't be worry about the size of this table... With proper database settings (indexes/partitions, etc...) it'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use three tables: country, item, item2country.

```
country: id, countryName, countryShort
item: id, itemName
item2country: id, itemId, countryId
```

This allows to search in the "item2country" table for an Item by ID and returns the target countryId. With this countryID lookup the full country name.
This is also easy for inserting new countries for an item. From the Item formular, which contains the ItemId, you just insert into "item2country".
Also, when you delete an Item from the table item, then also delete all id's in item2country where itemId.

Worst case warning: Do not store multiple country ids or shortnames into a single database field, like "en,us,au". That would be a desaster for search, because you would fetch and split over and over. This is very bad practise and sloooooowww.

Comment: "Worst case warning" yes this is what I said and I am trying to avoid.